# Flink checkpointing issue: "org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointFailureManager [] - Failed to trigger or complete checkpoint 1 for job"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, snapshot, checkpointing, savepoints

During flink checkpointing, if the folder where snapshot is to be saved is already present. Like in my case "chk-1" is the folder where snapshot is to be saved is already present. I get below exception & after that job gets restarted.

```
WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointFailureManager [] - Failed to trigger or complete checkpoint 1 for job 000000006e6b13320000000000000000. (0 consecutive failed attempts so far)
org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointException: Failure to finalize checkpoint.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Target file file:/opt/flink/pm/checkpoint/000000006e6b13320000000000000000/chk-1/_metadata already exists.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointMetadataOutputStream.getOutputStreamWrapper(FsCheckpointMetadataOutputStream.java:168)
```

Expectation:
Ideally it should either skip this folder name use another or overwrite the content of the existing folder.

Can someone help me out to know if this is expected behaviour or there is some workaround available?